How long "Status" field takes on SP List
I have a SP list but we want to see how long does someone takes a status from New to In-Progress to Review to Approve to Publish a document on SharePoint. Is there a way to know? Thank you.

There is no OOTB way for this. But you can enable version history in the list and later you can review version history for the items to see how much time it took between each status change. This will be the manual activity. Apart from this, you can customize your form and log the time when someone changes the status.

Could you tell me how that is done?


you can add a new date&time field like 'InProgressDate',

and a flow should set this field to current time when the status field became 'In Progress'

add an extra calculated field, where you subtract the two date from each other. The return data should be a number. Your formula:
=[InProgressDate]-[Created]
The result will show de date difference of the two dates in days. If you need a different timescale, you can multiply/divide as you wish.



Versioning creates a historical record of changes, with the date/time and an indication of the user who made the change, on a per-file/list item basis.
Reference:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/community/versioning-basics-best-practices
Here are steps: List/Library Settings ->Under General Settings->click the Versioning Settings link.

